# Чтение стрима в лист байтов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Видимо, ночь повлияла на меня окончательно, и я уже не соображаю.

Подскажите способ прочитать `DataInputStream` в `ArrayList<Byte>()`.

`AddAll`, разумеется, не работает при чтении стрима в массив байт.

И вообще, какой буфер лучше использовать для чтения из стримов?

Пробовал `ByteBuffer`, но мне показалось неудобным регулирование его размеров, если данные необходимо читать порциями (сначала 1 байт, потом 5, потом N, к примеру). Или я не правильно понял его работу? Сначала же нужно задать размер `.allocate(N)`, и только затем добавлять массив с помощью `.put(byte[])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любой наследник InputStream читается метод read(...) в массив byte[]. Потом этот массив можно переконвертировать в ArrayList<Byte>.

Например, вот так(на работоспособность не проверял):

```
    byte[] array = new byte[]{};
    List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for(byte b : array){
        list.add(b);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я так и делаю. Думал, есть вариант проще.

Есть ещё, конечно, каналы, но из них нельзя читать порцию, как я понял.

Comment: При использовании `ArrayList<Byte>` оверхед будет сумасшедшим - проще остаться с `byte[]`